# Как нарисовать эллипс?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Как нарисовать эллипс на яндекс.картах?

Answer (score 1):

Инструмента для рисования эллипсов в API Яндекс.Карт нет. Вы можете нарисовать либо круг, либо многоугольник, форма которого будет стремиться к эллипсу.